# How to iterate through a JSON response containing two objects in typescript?

Tags: json, angular, typescript

I am exporting an interface from a separate typescript file. While trying to iterate through the JSON response I am unable to parse it. I need to separate out one of  the objects from the JSON response and store it in another array.

This is the interface:

```
export interface IComplaintTagUri {
    id: string
    tag_uri: string
}
```

This is the typescript file where I am importing the interface:

```
tagCategories: IComplaintTagUri[];
dropdown = [];

ngOnInit() {
    this.tagCategories = [];

this.http.get<IComplaintTagUri[]>(tAPI.TagCategories).subscribe(result => {
    this.tagCategories = result;
    console.log("Result = ");
    console.log(result);
    console.log("Tag Categories = ");
    console.log(this.tagCategories);
  })
this.tagCategories.forEach(element => {
    this.dropdown.push(element.tag_uri);
    console.log(this.dropdown);
  }); 
console.log(this.dropdown);
}
```

I am able to successfully store the result in tagCategories. But when I try to store the tag_uri in another array it does not work.

It seems as though the for loop is never accessed and the last log shows dropdown as an empty array.

Can anyone tell me where I'm going wrong?

I tried including the forEach inside the subscribe function as well:

tagCategories: IComplaintTagUri[];
    dropdown = [];

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.tagCategories = [];

this.http.get<IComplaintTagUri[]>(tAPI.TagCategories).subscribe(result => {
    this.tagCategories = result;
    console.log("Result = ");
    console.log(result);
    console.log("Tag Categories = ");
    console.log(this.tagCategories);

this.tagCategories.forEach(element => {
  this.dropdown.push(element.tag_uri);
});
console.log(this.dropdown);

  })
}
```

Now the dropdown list prints to the console as a series of undefined objects.

Comment: `this.tagCategories.forEach` is **outside** the callback, so doesn't include the data from the subscription.

Comment: I tried including the forEach in the callback as well:
this.dataService.FireGET<IComplaintTagUri[]>(API.TagCategories).subscribe(result => {
    this.tagCategories = result;
    this.tagCategories.forEach(element => {
      this.dropdown.push(element.taguri);
    });
    console.log(this.dropdown);
  })
When I log the dropdown this time I get 40(number of tag_uri's) undefined objects

Comment: @PreetamOzarde Please put that code in the question as another edit (it's kind of hard to read in a comment). :)

Comment: @PreetamOzarde is this.tagCategories printing the values to consolue as you expect?

Comment: Yes it does print the results as expected

Comment: Look at my answer, you are getting undefined because you have `this.dropdown.push(element.taguri)`, you need: `this.dropdown.push(element.tag_uri)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Subscribe` is an asynchronous function, the `forEach` line will execute before the `subscribe` block is complete, So, when `forEach` is running, `tagCategories` probably doesn't contain any values. Solution is to move `forEach` inside the subscribe.

Second mistake you have is `this.dropdown.push(element.taguri)`, it should be `this.dropdown.push(element.tag_uri)`

```
this.http.get<IComplaintTagUri[]>(tAPI.TagCategories).subscribe(result => {
    this.tagCategories = result;
    console.log("Result = ");
    console.log(result);
    console.log("Tag Categories = ");
    console.log(JSON.stringify(this.tagCategories));//make sure you have the result as you expect

    this.tagCategories.forEach(element => {
      this.dropdown.push(element.tag_uri);
      console.log(this.dropdown);
    }); 
  })
}
```